# onRequestClose() method does not get called from react-native-modal

Tags: react-native, tvos, android-tv, amazon-fire-tv, react-native-modal

After I updated react native version to 0.73, the default modal of react native is not working as expected.

onRequestClose() method is not getting called while pressing menu button in tvOS and back button in Android TV or Fire TV.

Here is my code which I am using to show / hide the modal, but when I click on menu button or back button in the remote onRequestClose() method does not get called.

```
import { Modal } from "react-native";
<Modal
  visible={showModal}
  style={backgroundColor: '#000000'}
  animationType="fade"
  onRequestClose={() => setShowModal(false)}>
  <View>
    // Other UI elements here
  </View>
</Modal>
```

My expectation is, onRequestClose() method should get called so that I can perform some operation when modal gets closed.